# .NET Framework 3.5 not getting installed to run crystal report on cloud

Tags: .net

How to run report on cloud using crystal report without having to install .NET Framework 3.5? When I am trying to install .NET Framework 3.5, its not getting installed.

Comment: Could redefine your question or add more information? Now your question is: I installing XXX and it doesn't work. For example what is cloud? Azure? Amazon? Private cloud? which OS you got? etc.

Comment: In order to run crystal report on azure, .Net framework 3.5 is to be installed and its failing. i have windows 7, 64-bit

Answer (score 0):

Try to install higher version of .NET

Comment: it supports version 3.5 only